# Django 3: Filter queryset for letter or non-letter

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

In my database I have a table with items who's titles can start with a letter or a non-letter-character. For example a number or an "@" or a "#". The model looks like this:

```
class Items(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField
```

In my view I would like to separate the model into two objects. One objects that contains all the item with a title starting with a letter and an other object with all the other items:

```
class ItemsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        alpha_list = Items.objects.filter(title__startswith=<a letter>)
        other_list = Items.objects.filter(title__startswith=<not a letter>)

        context = {
            "list_a": alpha_list,
            "list_b": other_list
        }

        return context
```

I have been consulting the documents, stackoverflow and the holy google, but so far I have not been able to find a solution.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: regex is your best friend on this problem

Comment: And when you have gathered basic knowledge about how regex work, make some trials with https://regex101.com/ - that's a nice friend too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [regex](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#regex) to filter (use regex101.com to test your regex) and [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) to find other Items not start with a letter

start with a letter:

```
alpha_list = Items.objects.filter(title__regex=r'^[a-zA-Z].*$')
```

the other cases:

```
other_list = Items.objects.exclude(title__regex=r'^[a-zA-Z].*$')
```

Explanation:

```
/^[a-zA-Z].*$/

^ asserts position at start of the string 

a-z a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) (case sensitive) 

A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive) 

.* matches any character (except for line terminators)

* Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed 

$ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can slightly optimize the regular expression to:

```
# starts with an A-Za-z
Item.objects.filter(title__regex='^[A-Za-z]')

# starts not with A-Za-z
Item.objects.exclude(title__regex='^[A-Za-z]')
```

but a more important question is of course, what is a letter here. Here it will not match non-latin characters, such as Cyrillic, Arabic, etc. Furthermore it will not match characters with diacritics like `äöüßÄÖÜ`, etc. You can add extra characters or character ranges to the character block (the `[A-Za-z…]`) part to work with extra characters.

You can for example make use of [*Latin-1 Supplement* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)), [*Latin Extended-A* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended-A), [*Latin Extended-B* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended-B) and [*Latin Extended Addition* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended_Additional) as well with:

```
# starts with a Latin character
Item.objects.filter(title__regex='^[A-Za-z\uC0-\u024F\u1E00-\u1EFF]')
```

But we might want to add Arabic, Cyrillic, etc. characters as well.